# update Rxjs static merge Observable to version 6 syntax

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable, reactive-programming, rxjs6

How to update the old syntax of **Observable.merge()** in **rxjs 6+** ?
The old syntax looks like this: 
`Observable.merge(...array).map(() => {});`
What should be the correct syntax using **rxjs 6** ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import { merge } from 'rxjs';

merge(...array)
  .pipe(
    map(() => {}),
  )
```

If `merge` name collides with `merge` operator you can rename it:

```
import { merge as staticMerge } from 'rxjs';
```

Answer (score 2):

Adding on to [martin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/310726/martin)'s answer:

Since Rxjs 6, you can't directly chain your operators like `map` on an `Observable` value.

You'll have to `pipe` all your operators through the `Observable` value.

Everything that is used to create an `Observable` like `of`, `merge` etc, needs to be imported from `'rxjs'`

Every operator that you'll be using will be piped through a `pipe` operator and will be imported from `'rxjs/operators'`

---

**So in Rxjs 5 or previous:**

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

Observable.merge(...array).map(() => {});
```

**In Rxjs6 will turn to:**

```
import { merge } from 'rxjs';
import { map, ... } from 'rxjs/operators';

merge(...array).pipe(
  map(...),
  ...
);
```

### UPDATE:

`merge` returns an `Observable<T>` So if you want to return `Observable<CustomType[]>` just specify that while using `merge` like this:

```
merge<CustomType[]>(...array).pipe(
  map(...),
  ...
);
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.

Comment: the actual `merge` return a `Observable<void>`. How would adjust it to return a `Observable<customtype[]>` ?

Comment: No. It actually returns `Observable<T>`. So you can do something like `merge<CustomType[]>(...)` to make it return a value of type `CustomType[]`

Comment: Lifesaver especially on the **UPDATE** for `Observable`